# Is it possible to run a JavaScript file from a C# file?

Tags: javascript, c#

When I say JavaScript file, I mean the whole file. Not a function. I've seen ways to run a JavaScript function from c# but nothing about running a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1469790/13105088, one could run the command with any normal shell.

```cs
string strCmdText;
strCmdText= "/C node myscript.js"; // the command to run from the command prompt
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```

Note that this will show the Command Prompt on Windows.

This following script prevents that.

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C node myscript.js";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

(these example scripts were both provided by the answer I linked to above.)

In addition, you should probably also note:

> Important is that the argument begins with /C otherwise it won't work. How [Scott Ferguson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5007/scott-ferguson) said: it "Carries out the command specified by the string and then terminates."

Note: this is all assuming you are referring to NodeJS when you are saying a "JavaScript file", but any other interpreter (eg. `/C python3 myfile.py`) should also work.